# How does `min()` effect a Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, model, min

I am currently building an API using Laravel, and in order to learn Laravel as quickly as I possibly can, I am using another person's project to teach me the basics.

I have come across a bit of code that I cannot get my head around and was hoping that someone may be able to tell me what it is actually doing?

Here is the full code:

```
User::min()->find($this->id)->devices()->get();
```

Most of the above is obvious to me as I have been building this project for a month and resultantly, am very familiar with models. But the following snippet I cannot understand:

```
User::min()
```

Is `min()` the predefined PHP function, or is it a custom method on the model? Either way, how does it affect the retrieval from the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Check the User model and see if there's a scopeMin() defined there.

Comment: I already look at that but given there is no parameter set, I assumed it was something else... If there is no parameter set then how can it know which field to get the minimum of??

Comment: Check the User model and see if there's a scopeMin() defined somewhere. If that's not defined, I have no idea.

Comment: Nailed it! I learnt about scopes the other day, completely forgot! It is specifically selecting just the primary key. Makes sense based on the purpose of this function. Thank you very much. Can you update your answer to reflect your last comment. Then I will accept :D

Comment: why use a scope to get only the id? while you can use `->select('id')`

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja Well thats exactly why I am not going to implement that code. But, for the record, the primary key is not always `id`

Comment: @Ruffles Thank you very much! +1

Comment: @BenCarey I bet the developer isn't hardcoding the "id" key, but rather using something like *$query->select($this->primaryKey);* giving you the option to easily overwrite it

Comment: @iivannov Ahhhhh, I see!! That makes sense now... :-D